# How to execute query on every click using useLazyQuery()

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

Using `useLazyQuery()` hooks from `@apollo/react-hooks` I was able to execute a query on click of a button. But I cannot use it execute same query on consecutive clicks.

```
export default ({ queryVariables }) => {
  const [sendQuery, { data, loading }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DIRECTION, {
    variables: queryVariables
  });

  return <div onClick={sendQuery}>Click here</div>;
}
```

In the above the `sendQuery` executes only once.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

useLazyQuery uses the default network policy that of cache-first So I supposed your onClick function actually executes but because the returned value is what was in the cache, React notices no change in data as such the state is not updated since the returned data is what it already has that way no re-render and thing seem not to have changed. I suggest you should pass in a different network policy something like

```
  const [sendQuery, { data, loading }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DIRECTION, {
    variables: queryVariables,
    fetchPolicy: "network-only"
  });
```

This will mean you want the most recent information from your api hence basically no caching.
You might also want to experiment on other option and see which one best suits you
like `cache-and-network:` you can find out a little more here [understanding-apollo-fetch-policies](https://medium.com/@galen.corey/understanding-apollo-fetch-policies-705b5ad71980)

Comment: call the onClick like this `onClick={() => sendQuery()}`

Answer (score 3):

As per the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy), `useLazyQuery` accepts the parameter `fetchPolicy`.

```js
const [lazyQuery, { data, loading }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {
  fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
});
```

With `fetchPolicy` set to `no-cache`, the query's result is not stored in the cache.